# Reading and writing a public google sheet with python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have a public google sheet that has a bunch of license keys. I am trying to automate the read and write process from said sheet. eg. take code, run it, mark it as used.

After reading https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-read-and-write-data-to-google-spreadsheet-using-python-ebf54d51a72c

as well as the Google's tutorial https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project

Both of those instructed me to create a google cloud platform account. Since the sheet is public, has anyone managed to read/write without it?

Comment: https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make requests to a Google Workspace API with a Python command-line application, you need to complete a couple of steps in the Google Cloud Platform Console. In this case if you're using the Google Sheets API to access a Google Sheet even if is public, you need the following [prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python#prerequisites) which asks you to have a Google Cloud Platform project with the API enabled and create credentials for your application in the GCP console.

Comment: I guess there's no way around it huh. Should I be using an API key or the OAuth?

Comment: @LubyRong you can use either but in this specific scenario you can use [API key credentials](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#api-key) which is used to access public data anonymously. [OAuth client ID](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#oauth-client-id) credentials are used to authenticate as an end user, this requires your app to request and receive consent from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can read data (but not write afaik) if you have access to the sheet.  You can publish it and then read its output as a CSV.

To publish the sheet: File -> Share -> Publish to web.  Then in the Publish to web menu:  choose the sheet you want access to and CSV format, Publish.  Then copy the link.

With that link, we can easily use this Python code to download the CSV (replace `CSV_URL` with your link):

```
CSV_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)
    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    print(list(cr))
```